# Unable to enable development on iOS 10.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently having an issue with Xcode 8.2.1 not being able to activate developing on my iPhone 7 Plus (on iOS 10.1.1). Whenever I try to deploy an application, it gives me the following error:

> An error was encountered while enabling development on this device. Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000076)

In the iPhone's console, I found the following errors:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what I could possibly do to solve this issue? Any solutions I have found so far did not work at all. And yes, I did already try rebooting and reconnecting multiple times.

Comment: Try switching out your cable for a genuine Apple cable?

Comment: @owlswipe I am actually using the original Apple Lightning cable that came with my phone. Also I don't see how an alternate cable would have anything to do with the error shown in the console.

Comment: And have you tried the official suggestion of "rebooting and reconnecting the device"?

Comment: @owlswipe And have you tried to read my question in its entire form? If you don't bother reading the question, please refrain from answering.

Comment: Oh, my bad! How about: "For me, it had been set up in iTunes months back, but after opening up iTunes, selecting the device, and rejecting the prompt to upgrade it, only then would Xcode's Devices Organizer start re-downloading Symbol Files, and eventually it worked." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658727/cannot-connect-ipad-with-ios-9-to-xcode-7-1-beta-7b60

Comment: Also: "The problem is resolved after I updated iTunes to version 11.4 via Software Updates." http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qeHNjRs70PsJ:blogs.candoerz.com/question/146440/xcode-6-gm-with-iphone-5s-ios-8-gm-0xe8000070.aspx+&cd=17&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: And another: "In my case, during 2 years developing, my phone has several test app with name (null). you can only see a default Xcode app icon in app list in Setting. I had tried updating Xcode, but not work. finally I delete these null name apps, then Xcode - device can connect it without warning sign. Run test app won't get the error in question." http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qeHNjRs70PsJ:blogs.candoerz.com/question/146440/xcode-6-gm-with-iphone-5s-ios-8-gm-0xe8000070.aspx+&cd=17&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forgot to register your device with your develop account? I got that error code (0x8000076) when I forgot to register it. To double check:

- Find the identifier of your iPhone

  - In Xcode open the devices window (Window - Devices)
  - Select your phone and find its identifier
- Login to your developer account (https://developer.apple.com/account)
- Navigate to your devices (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/)
- Find the identifier in the list of devices.
- Check if the names are identical

If it is missing, create a new entry.

Comment: Indeed. The steps for an ad hoc Apple ID are different than a registered developer. Great suggestion and possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Those versions are not code signed anymore.

- Update Xcode
- verify or clarify if your code signing is going to be ad hoc or with a paid developer account
- update the iOS device
- verify the device is paired using Apple Configurator 2 and the command line tools or console app to inspect the system logs on the iOS device from the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error.  I had both Xcode beta installed and Xcode but was developing in Xcode.  Running the app via Xcode beta resolved the issue for me.